# Add Custome Field Error : Field does not exist openerp

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

Am trying to create a module that add some fields to product module .

i did the structure very well which i create "**init**.py , **openerp**.py , product_rolls_code.py , product_rolls_code_view.xml " .

After i run the Odoo , i get error : **Field `product_rolls` does not exist**
,if i go to database structure > fields , i can find product_rolls field is created .

Check out my code bellow

__ init__.py

```
import product_rolls_code
```

__ openerp__.py

```
{
'name': "Product Rolls",
'version': "1.0",
'category': "others",
'complexity': "normal",
'author': "Moayad Rayyan",
'depends': [
    "product" #name of module which is needed to be installed
],
'init_xml': [
    #place here the XML with initial data
],
'update_xml': [
    "product_rolls_code_view.xml",
],
'data': ['product_rolls_code_view.xml'],
'demo_xml': [],
'test': [],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
'application': False,
'images': [],
'js': [], }
```

product_rolls_code.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class product_rolls_code(osv.osv):

_inherit = "product.product"

_columns = {
    'product_rolls': fields.char('Product Rolls', size=11),
}
product_rolls_code()
```

product_rolls_code_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>    
    <record id="product_rolls_product" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.product.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <field name="ean13" position="after">
           <field name="product_rolls" />   
         </field>       
         </field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the field in the object product.product, while ure using the product.template in the model view. You should changue the inherited object in the py(producr.product) or changue the one in the view(product.template) so they are both the same.

Tip: use only data to add the view in the **openerp** file, delete the update.